# UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead. (FormEmailer)

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying using "FormEmailer" to send emails from spreadsheet while installing it i got this error  "UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead"  (line 756)

```
    function install(e) {
      var overwrite = e !== undefined ? true : false;
      var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle(NAME).setWidth(520).setHeight(180);
      c.ss = c.ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var langDefinitionUrl = 'https://sites.google.com/site/formemailer/translate/languages.txt?attredirects=0&d=1';
      var langs = UrlFetchApp.fetch(langDefinitionUrl).getContentText().split('\n');
      var locale = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale();
      var myLang = locale.split('_')[0];
      var found = false;
      var langList = css_(app.createListBox().setName("language"), _placeHolders);
      var langMap = {};
      var langCompat = 0;
      var firstLang = null;
      var count = 0;
      for( var i in langs ) {
        var csv = langs[i].split(',');
        if( csv[0] == 'versions' ) {
          langCompat = 0;
          for( var j = 1; j < csv.length; ++j )
            if( +csv[j] == VERSION ) {
              langCompat = 1;
              break;
            } else if( +csv[j] < VERSION )
              langCompat = 2;
        } else if( langCompat != 0 && langMap[csv[0]] === undefined ) {
          langMap[csv[0]] = 1;
          if( firstLang === null ) firstLang = csv[2];

          langList.addItem(csv[1]+(langCompat == 1 ? '' : '*'), langCompat+','+csv[2]);
          if( csv[0] == locale || !found && csv[0].split('_')[0] == myLang ) {
            found = csv[2];
            langList.setSelectedIndex(count);
          }
          ++count;
        }
      }
```

> UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead. (line 756, file "FormEmailer")

Comment: This isn't the support service of FormEmailer. If you would like to learn about HtmlService please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the Google Developpers Website that [UiApp has been depricated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app). This means that you cannot use its methods anymore - including `createApplication()`.

Instead you need to use the [Html service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My exp. in JS is very limited. that's why i asked for help. How to replace the error code with HTML service?

Comment: If you review the Html service reference linked to my answer, you will get ample information about implementing HTMLService. In short: You need to create an HTML file bound to your .gs file and  include JS code inside the <script> </script> part of the HTML code. Then, you need to create a doGet() function inside the .gs file and return the output of the HTML file with HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(). A script with a bound HTML cannot be run anymore by just pressing the "Play-button". Instead, you need to deploy it as a Web App:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web